# How to Add Sort drop down in Content search webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part

In SharePoint Online I want to sort search result by multiple fields for that I want to add sort dropdown in Content Search Web Part

[image]?

Comment: Do you mean you need multiple sort drop downs?

Comment: You would get the sorting by default in a Search Results Webpart. Any reason you can not use that? If not, use it instead :)

Comment: Requirement is to use only Content Search webpart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Content Search WebPart (CSWP), you need to develop this feature as part of the display template. In the control template, you can add the dropdown with the relevant sort values. In the dropdown change event, change the Content Search WebPart's query with the appropriate sorting (based on managed property) by using 
[Srch.U.fillKeywordQuery function](http://www.eliostruyf.com/dynamically-changing-result-source-sharepoint-2013-search-center/).

Sample code - dynamically changes the result source

```
if (typeof Srch.U.fillKeywordQuery !== 'undefined') {
    // Override the fillKeywordQuery function
    var originalFillKeywordQuery = Srch.U.fillKeywordQuery;
    // Override the default fillKeywordQuery function
    Srch.U.fillKeywordQuery = function(query, dp) { 
        console.log(dp.get_id());
        dp.set_sourceID('70949b02-0f2c-4026-9c4f-c9d6e0023aa4');
        // Call the default function to go further with the query processing
        originalFillKeywordQuery(query, dp);
    };
}
```